# Drawinterface problem and drag and drop - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, paint

I'm a beginner in Java and I want to move some piece. how can I drag and drop this 3 piece?

This project is to drag and drop like a puzzle game.

```
import Model.*;
import View.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Nivel1 {

    NewJFrame nf;

    Shape s1;
    Shape s2;
    Shape s3;
    Shape mm1;
    Point p = new Point(0, 0);

    public Nivel1() {

        this.nf = new NewJFrame();
        nf.setVisible(true);

        this.s1 = ShapeFactory.getShapeInstance("1");
        s1.setX(80);
        s1.setY(80);

        this.s2 = ShapeFactory.getShapeInstance("2");
        s2.setX(80);
        s2.setY(200);

        this.s3 = ShapeFactory.getShapeInstance("3");
        s3.setX(80);
        s3.setY(320);

        this.mm1 = ShapeFactory.getShapeInstance("m1");
        mm1.setX(80);
        mm1.setY(80);

        nf.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
                // System.out.println("componentResized");
                paintInterface();
            }

        });

        nf.pack();
        nf.revalidate();
        nf.repaint();

    }


    public void paintInterface() {
        Graphics g = nf.getGraphics();
        nf.paintComponents(g);
        mm1.draw(g);
        s1.draw(g);
        s2.draw(g);
        s3.draw(g);
    }

}
```

[image]

AND My second problem is with the paint function. Whenever I do run my app, there is nothing appears after I resize `Jframe`. Thanks!

Comment: You're doing Swing graphics incorrectly. Never call paintComponents directly as you're doing and never draw directly in the JFrame but instead draw within the paintComponent method of a JPanel as per the standard Swing tutorials. As for dragging sprites, add a mouse listener and mouse motion listener and use your code logic to identify when a shape has been clicked (the Shape contains method works well for this). Plenty of examples of this on this site, easily found with a little searching.

Comment: Here's a link to a relevant tutorial: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). You can find links to other key Swing tutorials and resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: Also, do not set the frame visible before you add components to it and pack it. Then your revalidate() and repaint() calls are unnecessary.